# How to get current datetime in unix timestramp in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestramp, `1559885284236` and a function to generate readable datetime format.

```
def tz_from_utc_ms_ts(utc_ms_ts, tz_info):
    """Given millisecond utc timestamp and a timezone return dateime

    :param utc_ms_ts: Unix UTC timestamp in milliseconds
    :param tz_info: timezone info
    :return: timezone aware datetime
    """
    # convert from time stamp to datetime
    utc_datetime = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_ms_ts / 1000.)

    # set the timezone to UTC, and then convert to desired timezone
    return utc_datetime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC')).astimezone(tz_info)




import datetime as dt
import pytz

utc_ts = 1559885284236
utc_time = "Sat Sep 22 22:16:29 2018 UTC"
pdt_time = "Sat Sep 22 15:16:29 2018 PDT"

tz_dt = tz_from_utc_ms_ts(utc_ts, pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))

print(tz_dt)
print(tz_dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

which gives,

```
2019-06-06 22:28:04.236000-07:00
06-06-2019
```

as expected, but how can I convert a current datetime value to the unix ms with 13 length.

when I try,

```
dt.datetime.timestamp(dt.datetime.now())
```

which gives, `1560004646.952688` this is not my expected 13 digit value, pls help.

Comment: Cast it to an integer using int(1560004646.952688)

Comment: that gives only 10 characters

Comment: Then  `int(1560004646.952688 * 1000)`